# Проблема с выводом в консоль в питоне через библиотеку sys

Tags: python

```
import sys
n = sys.stdin.read()
Ans = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
sys.stdout.write(" ".join(sorted(Ans)))
```

Всё считывает прекрасно, но почему-то ничего не выводит в консоль, даже ошибку не выдаёт.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `sys.stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, Вам нужно закончить ввод. Нажмите `CTRL+D` (UNIX) или `CTRL+Z` (Windows). Если не сработает ни то, ни другое, тогда проверьте, ту ли раскладку клавиатуры Вы используете. Должна быть включена английская.

В отличие, например, от `input()`, `sys.stdin.read()` не знает, что ввод должен заканчиваться переносом строки. Для того, чтобы сообщить, что ввод закончен, нужно выполнить команду, которую я указал выше. После этого, Вашей программе будет отправлен сигнал `EOF`.

Отметим, что `CTRL+C` прервёт выполнение программы и Вы не получите результата.